# Sorting by a property of NHibernate component without explicitly specifying it?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I've got two entities:

```
class Complex
{
    public virtual MyComponent Component { get; set; }
    public virtual string OtherProperty { get; set; }
}

class MyComponent
{
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

`Component` property of `Complex` is mapped in NHibernate as a component. I would like NHibernate to always use `MyComponent`'s `Number` property when sorting by `MyComponent`. So whenever I write:

```
session.Query<Complex>().OrderBy(x => x.Component)
```

I would like the result to be sorted only by `Number` and not `Description` - right now NHibernate sorts by both columns. It would be great if the solution worked both in Linq and HQL.

I looked at `LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry`. I could use it to generate proper HQL for that, but I would need to register a generator for every property of type `MyComponent` (so if I have more entities like `Complex` I would need to register it many times), and I want this kind of sorting to be used always when sorting by property of this type.

Is it possible in NHibernate?